Power BI usage metrics
I tried to export data of usage metrics. But when I did data validation,I observed power bi is only capturing usage metrics data within the workspace.But I want to see usage metrics data for the report which I have published on the web. Can anyone please help me how to do this.
I tried to export data of usage metrics. But when I did data validation,I observed power bi is only capturing usage metrics data within the workspace.But I want to see usage metrics data for the report which I have published on the web. Can anyone please help me how to do this.
